# Yet another No Reverse Match

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have impletmented the detailview with views.py this afternoon.

I have a model with the pk set as a UUID.

the URLs line concerned is:

```
path('user/detail/<uuid:pk>', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='userdetail'),
```

the template referring to it is:

```
<a href="{%  url 'userdetail' user.pk %}">
```

which is generating the following URL:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/user/detail/809b0ec2-d604-4171-8966-0817bfd59c88

however I get:

Reverse for 'userdetail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/user/detail/(?P[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})$'].

If I use the username e.g. email from AbstractBase User, the detail view doesn't like it as it wants Pk or slug.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am including the model below;

```
class UserDetails(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
FormFieldUserID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
FormFieldTitle = models.CharField(max_length=75, help_text='Enter title',
                                  verbose_name="Enter")
FormFieldFirstName = models.CharField(max_length=75, help_text='Enter First Name',
                                      verbose_name="First Name")  # Users First Name
FormFieldMiddleName = models.CharField(max_length=75, help_text='Enter Middle Name', blank=True,
                                       verbose_name="Middle Names")  # Users middle name
FormFieldLastName = models.CharField(max_length=75, help_text='Enter Last Name',
                                     verbose_name="Last Name")  # users last name
email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, help_text="Enter Username/email",
                          verbose_name="Email Address")  # user email
FormFieldUserImg = ResizedImageField(size=[40,40], crop=['middle', 'center'], upload_to='project/images/',
                                 help_text="Choose project image", blank=True)
FormFieldAddr1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter Address',
                                  verbose_name="Address 1")  # Users Address
FormFieldAddr2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter Address', blank=True,
                                  verbose_name="Address 2")  # Users Address
FormFieldAddr3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter Address', blank=True,
                                  verbose_name="Address 3")  # Users Address
FormFieldAddr4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter Address', blank=True,
                                  verbose_name="Address 4")  # Users Address
FormFieldCounty = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter County',
                                   verbose_name="County")  # Users county
FormFieldCountry = CountryField(help_text='Select user country', verbose_name="Country")  # Users country
FormFieldAddrCode = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text='Enter zip/post code',
                                     verbose_name="Post Code")  # Users Post Code
FormFieldMobileNo = models.CharField(max_length=25, help_text="Enter Mobile Phone Number",
                                     verbose_name="Mobile Number")  # User mobile Number
FormFieldPhoneNo = models.CharField(max_length=25, help_text="Enter Phone Number",
                                    verbose_name="Phone Number",blank=True)  # User phone Number
FormFieldWebAddr = models.CharField(max_length=254, help_text='Enter website details',
                                    verbose_name="Website Details",blank=True)  # User Website details
FormFieldUserNotes = models.CharField(max_length=254, help_text='Enter any user notes',
                                      verbose_name="User Notes",blank=True)  # User notes
FormFieldDateAdded = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, help_text='Date user added',
                                          verbose_name="User added date")
FormFieldAddedBy = models.CharField(default=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, max_length=200,
                                    help_text='Select update detail', verbose_name="Used added by")
# Fields required by Abstract Model for users auth
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Is User Active',
                                verbose_name="User Active")  # Default must be true )
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Is user an administrator',
                               verbose_name="Admin User")  # Default must be false)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
objects = CustomUserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    """Does the user have a specific permission?"""
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    """Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"""
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

@property
def is_staff(self):
    """Is the user a member of staff?"""
    # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
    return self.is_admin

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'User Detail'
    verbose_name_plural = 'User Details'
```

Comment: It looks like you did not pass a variable with the name `user` to the template.

Comment: not sure what you mean by user? I pass the UUID for the user account. Are you saying I should be passing something else?

Comment: In your template you use `<a href="{%  url 'userdetail' user.pk %}">`, so that means it looks for a variable named `user` to obtain `user.pk` from. If there is no such user, then of course it can not obtain the `.pk`.

Comment: User.pk is passed from a view in the form of a dictionary {‘user’:user} it is passing the user.pk which from the model is FormFieldUserID set as a primary key. Not sure what it is I’m not doing right. I’ve edited the original post to include the model.

Answer (score 0):

put this because your path it's nedd to pk (int or str ...)

```
<a href="{%  url 'userdetail' pk=user.pk %}">
```

if don't work  put this :

```
path('user/detail/<str:pk>', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='userdetail'),
```

Comment: trieed both methods - both unfortunatley didnt work: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/user/detail/7b232965-0ba1-42d2-9a0b-18a363cc8add
Reverse for 'userdetail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/user/detail/(?P<pk>[^/]+)$']